# SetWindowPos has not effect on tooltip

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, winapi

I am trying to give my ComboBox an in place tooltip for long strings. However when I call SetWindowPos on the tooltip, the position is never changed. Called when TTN_SHOW is received:

```
::SetWindowPos(textTooltip, NULL, TipRect.left, TipRect.top, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOACTIVATE | SWP_NOZORDER);
```

If I remove the SWP_NOSIZE flag and pop in some values into the width/height, then the combo box changes size to these values but the position remains the same. SetWindowPos always returns TRUE.

The tip is initialised like so:

```
        textTooltip = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_TRANSPARENT, TOOLTIPS_CLASS, NULL, TTS_NOPREFIX, 0, 0, 0, 0, this->GetSafeHwnd(), NULL, NULL, NULL);
        if(!textTooltip)
            return;

        ZeroMemory(&ToolInfo, sizeof(TOOLINFO));
        ToolInfo.cbSize = sizeof(TOOLINFO);
        ToolInfo.uFlags = TTF_TRANSPARENT | TTF_SUBCLASS; 
        ToolInfo.hwnd = this->GetSafeHwnd();
        ToolInfo.lpszText = "place holder"; //set in OnSelectChangeOk
        ToolInfo.uId = 0;   
        ToolInfo.rect = TipRect; //rect is re-set in OnSelectChangeOk

        ::SendMessage(textTooltip, TTM_ADDTOOL, 0, (LPARAM)&ToolInfo);
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Yeah, you are missing the code that checks the return value and calls GetLastError() to find out what's wrong.

Comment: I stripped out most of the error checking when posting to make it a little cleaner. As stated in the post SetWindowsPos returns TRUE therefore GetLastError() returns 0. The call to SendMessage also returns TRUE. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you gotta do `::SendMessage(hToolWnd, TTM_TRACKPOSITION, 0, MAKELPARAM(x, y));` and set the `TTF_ABSOLUTE` flag in the `ToolInfo.uFlags` member!

Fore more information, refer to: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb760422(VS.85).aspx

Comment: Won't this require me to manually show/hide the tooltip though? TTF_ABSOLUTE requires TTF_TRACK also be set, which means that I have to use TTM_TRACKACTIVE and TTM_TRACKPOSITION. I have considered this approach, maybe checking for WM_MOVE messages, then showing up the tip but it is a little dirtier than I would hoped. I was basing my implementation from http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/06/26/647365.aspx?PageIndex=2 and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb760252(VS.85).aspx#tooltip_sample_inplace

Comment: ok.. the code from me was used for a balloon tool tip which always should pop up at a specified position. Do you also send TTM_ADJUSTRECT and return TRUE after receiving the TTN_SHOW notification, like in the article you mentioned? The comment after the return TRUE says "suppress default positioning" so perhaps you forgot this?

Comment: Yea, The return TRUE prevents the standard routine being called for the message. I have taken a slightly different route now and I am calling TrackMouseEvent to get ON_WM_MOUSEHOVER messages, then on the hover I manually move and display the tooltip. Not as clean but it seems to do the job.